Estimating $p$th moment bound of error between small noise SDE and ODE
For a $d$-dimensional standard Brownian motion $W$, and a locally Lipschitz function $b: \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$, consider an SDE:
$$dX_t^\varepsilon = b(X_t) dt + \varepsilon^t dW_t,\quad\text{where $0 < \varepsilon < 1$.}$$
Let's assume that this SDE satisfies the integrability criteria required for the well-posedness.
As $t \rightarrow \infty$, this SDE becomes an ODE:
$$dX_t= b(X_t) dt.$$
How could we estimate the $p$th moment bound of error between $X_t^\varepsilon$, and $X_t$ for $p \geq 1$ for any $t > 0$?
If $b$ is globally Lipschitz, we can use the usual coupling method, and apply Gronwall's inequality. Even in this case, we get an estimate that depends on time, where the bounding coefficient blows up exponentially. So it would be a finite-time result.
I have looked through potentially relevant post:
Small noise limits with irregular drift.
But such result is for bounded $b(X_t)$.
I also have gone through this paper: "ZERO NOISE LIMIT OF A STOCHASTIC DIFFERENTIAL
EQUATION INVOLVING A LOCAL TIME" by Kuwada and Matsumura, but their result is local in time, and is one-dimensional result.
Could someone recommend some relevant literature on this?
I don't have a rigorous training in SDE, so this may be something a bit basic. Any helpful hints would be very much appreciated.

Update -- I found a nice reference: "Small random perturbations of peano phenomena" (https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/17442508208833208)
This paper shows a.s. convergence of the sol to SDEs in multi-dimension (under certain conditions)
What can we say about pth moment of the error, $\mathbb{E}|X^{\varepsilon}_t - X_t|^p$ then?

I think we can say that this converges to 0 if we can find a dominating r.v. Y s.t. $|X^{\varepsilon}_t| \leq Y_t$ , then apply dominated convergence theorem. Is this line of thought valid?

Also, is there a way to quantify how fast the error term converges to 0 w.r.t. $\varepsilon$?



I think a good starting point to look at would be the Burkholder-Davis-Gundy inequality, e.g. Le Gall Theorem 5.16

@optimal_transport_fan / Thank you for the response. But I was already aware of that when writing the post, and had looked at it a long time ago. That only gives finite-time result, which is what I explained above. The coupling argument that I mentioned in the original post was referring to using BDG inequality.
